# How does the map $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ send every point from $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I'm doing exercises on homotopy equivalences and trying in the process of showing that $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \simeq S^1$. Now my question isn't really related to the homotopy equivalence, but rather than the fact that how come it is that the map $$(x,y) \mapsto \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ sends every point from $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1$? I cannot seem to figure out how this is constructed?

Comment: This is written slightly wrongly.  The map is $\mathbf{v} \mapsto \frac{\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}$ where $\mathbf{v}=\langle x, y \rangle$.  You seem to be using $x$ twice:  once as a vector, and once as a coordinate in the same vector.

Comment: Is $\mathbf{v}=\langle x, y \rangle$ the inner product of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No, it is the ordered pair $(x,y)$.  Just make all my pointy brackets rounded if you like.

Comment: @Randall I see. Edited.

Comment: In short,  it should map to $(x,y)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in your notation.

Comment: You should either write $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute the length of the output vector:  it clearly has length $1$.  The map is well-defined because the denominator is zero if and only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$, which has been expressly prohibited from being in your domain.

Comment: I see thanks. Is there a similar map if I would consider a circle with radius $r$ instead of $1$?

Comment: Sure.  There is an obvious expansion map from a circle of radius 1 to one of radius $r$:  map $(x,y)$ to $(rx, ry)$.  Now compose with this map.